# Select end of range in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, range, element

Suppose I have an element with 7 text children `<div>abcdefg</div>`and a range of [1]-[4] `bcd`. How can I place the users cursor at the end of this range (right after `d`) without changing the range start?

I'm looking for something like `window.getSelection().addRange(range.end)`

Comment: Did you try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange (if element happen to be an html input element) ?

Comment: Doesn't look like setSelectionRange() works for contenteditable="true" elements functioning as inputs.

Comment: Ok. Contenteditable is a mine field ! https://ckeditor.com/blog/ContentEditable-The-Good-the-Bad-and-the-Ugly/ is worth a read if you try want a broad view about it.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question. From what I understand you want to extend the range right after the end of the current range.

To do that you could use something like this:

```js
const node = window.getSelection().focusNode;

const range = new Range();
range.setStart(node, 1);
range.setEnd(node, 4);

// Modify the range to extend the end (I've added +1 to go beyond it)
range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);

// Apply the range
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

This might also help: [`Selection.extend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/extend)

I hope this answers your question. Let me know if you need further clarification.